# Difficulties with intents and several activities

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a main activity that launch the application. In the main activity I have an `ImageView` that will get the string of a path from a selected thumbnails from a `GridView` in a second activity via an intent.

This perhaps sounds strange and would be more naturally to launch the second activity first with the `GridView`, but this is a requirement for the task.

So I'm struggling with the difficulties how to deal with the string `imageId` that expects the intent from the second activity? I guess I will have to put a button to open the second activity and the `GridView` like a menu button, but any ideas how to deal with the intent thing? Appreciate some help!

Code in the main activity:

```
String imageId = i.getExtras().getString("image");

ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);

Bitmap bitmap =BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageId);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

open the second activity using `startActivityForResult`, something like:

to start the second activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

Then handle the returned result:

```
 @Override

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
       String imageId = data.getExtras().getString("image");

       ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);

       Bitmap bitmap =BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageId);
       imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

In the second actitivty, when a thumbnail is selected:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.putExtra("image", path);
 setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
 finish();
```

check https://stackoverflow.com/a/10407371/1434631

Comment: I get a red line below the onActivityResult and the message is: void is an invalid type for the variable onActivityResult ??

Comment: Perhaps it was wrong to place that code within the onCreate method, better when I moved it outside!

Comment: Almost there! I get a red line below Intent i = new Intent(this, Activity_2.class); in the onClick method! Why?

Comment: It's working when I use getApplicationContect instead of "this"

Comment: Your code is working but there is a strange thing. In activity 1 I have the ImageView and also a button to open activity 2 to show the GridView. But if a place the button after the ImageView in the layout file, the application force a close! What could be the reason for that?

Comment: OK! Thanks for the help! I guess I can you this code to open other activities and pass data back.